# JMeter: Testing for Exceptions from ResponseData

Tags: exception, jmeter

I have the following code in a BeanShell PostProcessor that would confirm that a 404 error response code is being received:

if  (prev.getResponseCode().equals("404") == true) { 
    prev.setResponseOK();

}

Rather than looking at the Response Code, I want to be able to search for text in the Response Data instead for this request and then use the prev.setResponseOK().

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use:

> prev.getResponseDataAsString()

But if all you want to do is check that a text is present, why not use a [ResponseAssertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)